# Windows CMD - Rename files based on folder name

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

File structure: Dashboards > Individual Folders [Spencer Farris, Tyler Manson, Alexis Gibb, Ashley Edminston] > Dashboard

I know you can rename a file with the simple `ren` command and to get to the folder using `cd`, but I don't know how to rename them based on the folder name. So I have the folder structure noted above. I want to loop through all the folders in the Dashboards folder, go into each folder, and rename the Dashboard.xlsx file to "Spencer Farris Dashboard.xlsx" "Tyler Manson Dashboard.xlsx" etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For command line in same folder (top-level folder tree):

---

```
cd /d "c:\folder_target\" & for /d /r %i in (*)do ren "%i\Dashboards.xlsx" "%~ni Dashboards.xlsx"
```

---

For bat/cmd file:

---

```
@echo off 
cd /d "c:\folder_target\"
For /D /R %%i in (*)do ren "%%i\Dashboards.xlsx" "%%~ni Dashboards.xlsx"
```

---

You can do this using **[`For /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html)** and **`/R`**